Prevent Child rebuilding in flutter parent widget
Hope you're well. I'm developing an application in which I have several child widgets in parent widgets that are also children, and so on. Everything works fine except the reconstruction.
Indeed, if I modify the properties of the parent widget, the whole tree is rebuilt (normal since I'm using a StatefulWidget).
My question is, how can I prevent children from being rebuilt when the parent changes?
PS: All widgets have properties, so “const” won't work.
I've tried using bloc but I can't really find my way around.
    class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ParentWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int parentValue = 0;
  int child1Value = 0;
  int child2Value = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
      SizedBox(
          width: context.screenWidth,
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('Value of parent : $parentValue'),
                Child1(value: child1Value),
                Child2(value: child2Value)
              ])),
      Positioned(
          right: 10,
          bottom: 10,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
              onPressed: () => setState(() => parentValue++),
              child: const Icon(RemixIcons.add_line))),
      Positioned(
          right: 10,
          bottom: 80,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              onPressed: () => setState(() => child1Value++),
              child: const Icon(RemixIcons.add_line))),
      Positioned(
          right: 10,
          bottom: 150,
          child: FloatingActionButton(
              backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
              onPressed: () => setState(() => child2Value++),
              child: const Icon(RemixIcons.add_line)))
    ]));
  }
}

class Child1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Child1({super.key, required this.value});
  final int value;

  @override
  State<Child1> createState() => _Child1State();
}

class _Child1State extends State<Child1> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log('Rebuild du 1');
    return Text('Value of child 1 : ${widget.value}');
  }
}

class Child2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Child2({super.key, required this.value});
  final int value;

  @override
  State<Child2> createState() => _Child2State();
}

class _Child2State extends State<Child2> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    log('Rebuild du 2');
    return Text('Value of child 2 : ${widget.value}');
  }
}


If it's expensive to rebuild a widget, you probably don't have proper separation of model and view.

Why don't you share your entire code with community? Generally I think we should just rebuild the smallest child that is necessary for our app and avoid rebuilding and using setState and Statefulwidgets for the parent widgets.

Have edited my post to add full code of my widget tree. Thank you

and you would like not to rebuild Child2? if so, why? is it a very complicated widget which is very expensive to rebuilt? or something else?

It's too costly to rebuild Child2, as it may be a widget with other children. It's therefore very cumbersome to rebuild it each time its parent is modified. To get an idea, I want to create an application like Canvas

Try using RepaintBoundary

@Alejandro Cumpa
is not working

"""It's too costly to rebuild Child2, as it may be a widget with other children""" - ok so how many children do you expect to be? 10, 20, hundreds, more? and how oftten do you want to rebuild your parent widget?

I can have a Row, inside which I put 2 Containers (Container1 and Container2), and in Container 2 I put another Row with other containers, and so on. There's no limit to the number of new widgets you can add, as this is an application for drawing views, a bit like Canvas.
The problem is that changing the mainAxisAlignment of my Row (the first widget), flutter rebuilds all its child widgets and so on.
How can I change a property of my Row without rebuilding all the widgets inside?

And this same widget can be in a Positioned widget, and if every time I move my Positioned widget all its children are rebuilt, it becomes very CPU-intensive.

I would recommend you to do not use setState() not matter if you are using const it will rebuild the whole widget tree.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MaterialApp(home: ParentWidget()));

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
const ParentWidget({super.key});

 @override
 State<ParentWidget> createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {

final ValueNotifier<int> parentValue = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
final ValueNotifier<int> child1Value = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
final ValueNotifier<int> child2Value = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(children: [
  SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
              valueListenable: parentValue,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Text('Value of parent : ${parentValue.value}');
              },
            ),
            Child1(valueNotifier: child1Value),
            Child2(valueNotifier: child2Value)
          ])),
  Positioned(
      right: 10,
      bottom: 10,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          onPressed: () =>  parentValue.value++,
          child: const Icon(Icons.abc))),
  Positioned(
      right: 10,
      bottom: 80,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          onPressed: () => child1Value.value++,
          child: const Icon(Icons.abc_outlined))),
  Positioned(
      right: 10,
      bottom: 150,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
          onPressed: () => child2Value.value++,
          child: const Icon(Icons.abc_sharp)))
   ]));
 }
}

 class Child1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Child1({super.key, required this.valueNotifier});
  final ValueNotifier<int> valueNotifier;

  @override
  State<Child1> createState() => _Child1State();
 }

class _Child1State extends State<Child1> {

@override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   print('Rebuild du 1');

   return ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
   valueListenable: widget.valueNotifier,
   builder: (context, value, child) {
    return Text('Value of child 1 : ${widget.valueNotifier.value}');
   },
 );
 }
}

class Child2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Child2({super.key, required this.valueNotifier});
  final ValueNotifier<int> valueNotifier;

   @override
   State<Child2> createState() => _Child2State();
 }

 class _Child2State extends State<Child2> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   print('Rebuild du 2');
   return ValueListenableBuilder<int>(
        valueListenable: widget.valueNotifier,
        builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Text('Value of child 2 : ${widget.valueNotifier.value}');
     },
   );
 }
}


I finally found the solution using a StatefulBuilder. It works perfectly.

Yes you can also use that one both are similar
